# I have a problem creating a view with different names from the original table

Tags: sql, view

I'm trying to create a view with the following code:

```
CREATE VIEW School_Rating (School_Name, Safety_Rating, Family_Rating, 
    Environment_Rating, Instruction_Rating, Leaders_Rating, Teachers_Rating)
AS
SELECT 
    NAME_OF_SCHOOL, 
    Safety_Icon,
    Family_Involvement_Icon, 
    Environment_Icon,
    Instruction_Icon, 
    Leaders_Icon,
    Teachers_Icon
FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error, telling me that "Safety_Icon" is not valid in this context

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Could you also add the output of `show create table CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS;` to the question, please?

Comment: Yes!
Status:
Failed
Error message
"SAFETY_ICON" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
Learn more about this error

Comment: @digijay , unfortunately I can't. I have the table created from a previous exercise. I'm just reusing for this one

Answer (score 0):

Now it's working...

CREATE VIEW School_Rating (School_Name, Safety_Rating, Family_Rating,
Environment_Rating, Instruction_Rating, Leaders_Rating, Teachers_Rating)
AS SELECT
NAME_OF_SCHOOL,
"Safety_Icon",
"Family_Involvement_Icon",
"Environment_Icon",
"Instruction_Icon",
"Leaders_Icon",
"Teachers_Icon"
FROM CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS